# How do I download pictures from iPhone 7 to Ubuntu PC

Tags: file-sharing, iphone

I can connect my iPhone via USB to a Dell/Windows PC and it immediately recognizes it as a file folder and allows me to download pics.

I can't get my Ubuntu to connect with iPhone. Is there a simple solution?  I need to download pictures from iPhone 7 to Dell laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: I believe connecting to iPhone requires iTunes or similar apple software.

Answer (score 0):

Since ~5 years ago it is not possible.

I finally gave up.

But there’s something much more convenient: let your photos automatically upload to Dropbox.

I know, it’s not free software but neither is our iPhone ;-)